# Where does the Java Card "Converter" Tool look for EXP files?

Tags: javacard

using the JavaCard Converter tool, I kept getting errors like

```
error: export file rmi.exp of package java.rmi not found.
```

and

```
error: export file framework.exp of package javacard.framework not found.
```

The errors disappeared gradually after I copied the directories beneath

```
/usr/local/javacard/java_card_kit-2_2_2/api_export_files
```

to the local directory.  Now, that's clearly a hack. No, calling this a 'hack' would be an insult to just about any other *real* hack.  This is clearly not how things are supposed to work, right?

So, how do I tell the converter tool where it should be looking for the .exp-files?

And, yes, I've set `JC_HOME=/usr/local/javacard/java_card_kit-2_2_2`, too.

Answer (score 4):

Quote from Java Card 2.1 Development Kit User’s Guide - November 15, 1999 document:

"
You can use the -exportpath command option to specify the locations of export
files. The path consists of a list of root directories in which the Converter looks for
export files. Export files must be named as the last portion of the package name
followed by the extension .exp. Export files are located in a subdirectory called
javacard, following the Java Card directory naming convention.

For example, to load the export file of the package java.lang, if you have specified
-exportpath as c:\myexportfiles, the Converter searches the directory
c:\myexportfiles\java\lang\javacard for the export file lang.exp.
"

I suppose it should apply for 2.2.2 too.
So use appropriate `-exportpath` option for converter to point to your exp files and be sure the javacard subdir is created under the package dir for holding exp files.